# Trying to access user ip address of the visitor from local host but instead of showing 127.0.0.1 it is displaying ::1

Tags: php, mysql, database, ip

```
<?php

    require 'connection.php';

    $user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    echo $user_ip;

?>
```

Output being displayed

> ::1

I am just practicing to get the visitor ip to count that how many vistors have visit the website.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should a MAMP return ::1 as IP on localhost?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699454/should-a-mamp-return-1-as-ip-on-localhost)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much simple one:

```
<?php
    $user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']?:($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']?:$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']);
    echo $user_ip;
?>
```

Comment: Here(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799808/how-do-i-count-unique-visitors-to-my-site) is the full solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your webserver is listening on ipV6.

Try the following:

- Find your webserver configuraion (httpd.conf)
- Look for the line

> Listen 80

- Change it to 0.0.0.0:80 so it looks as follows:

> Listen 0.0.0.0:80

[Reff](http://board.issociate.de/thread/489575/SERVERquotREMOTEADDRquot-returning-1.html)

Comment: # Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 127.0.0.1
 where to change i have changed at last line 8o to 127.0.0.1 and after stoping services i restart my server but it is not working server icon is showing working