# How to build a view counter for my posts using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wanna build a view counter functionality for my website just like here on stackoverflow view counter:
[View counter functionality in stackoverflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LF4b8.jpg)
I know how to build that, each time a user hit the post url, increment its view times by one. But the problem is that a user can come and refresh the page as much as he wants. How to fix that? any suggestion? I will be really glad if you can tell me the algorithm or code of that.

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799808/how-do-i-count-unique-visitors-to-my-site

Answer (score -1):

You can customize this code to your POST function << 
Good lock (:

```
var http = require('http');

var userCount = 0;
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {

userCount++;
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
res.write('Hello!\n');
res.write('We have had ' + userCount + ' visits!\n');
res.end();
});

server.listen(9090);
console.log('server Up and running... 9090');
```