# How to get Blog Posts seen visitor in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I Have Blog web project based on Asp.net Core. I want to Get Count of Visitor that seen each one of posts in My Blog. when call Get Method Request for it, for example http:site.com/post?id=2323 .then Save Them to the Database Without duplicate user visit.(each user can increase one visit count at the time) .what is the best way for save visit count. Use of IP Address or Not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I count unique visitors to my site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799808/how-do-i-count-unique-visitors-to-my-site)

Comment: first you need to decide how exactly you are going to define a "unique" visitor. There could be more than one way to describe that. Hint: IP address is, by itself, not a good way to decide if a visitor is unique or not - the same public IP is commonly shared between multiple devices (think NAT on a home router, or a corporate proxy). And these days with wifi and 4G and so on, devices can move between networks frequently (and thus their public IP address can change frequently). It might be useful as part of a set of data which is used to determine uniqueness, though.

Comment: But if you ever want more than this very basic count of visitors, you'd probably be better to avoid re-inventing the wheel and plug in a ready-made analytics package like google analytics or something similar.